# How to delete all instances of a character in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

How do I delete all the instances of a character in this string? Here is my code:

```
def findreplace(char, string):
    place = string.index(char)
    string[place] = ''
    return string
```

However, if I run this, this is what happens:

```
>>> findreplace('i', 'it is icy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in findreplace
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 176):

Strings are immutable in Python, which means once a string is created, you cannot alter the contents of the strings. If at all, you need to change it, a new instance of the string will be created with the alterations.

Having that in mind, we have so many ways to solve this

1. Using [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace),

   ```
   >>> "it is icy".replace("i", "")
   't s cy'
   ```
2. Using [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate),

   ```
   >>> "it is icy".translate(None, "i")
   't s cy'
   ```
3. Using Regular Expression,

   ```
   >>> import re
   >>> re.sub(r'i', "", "it is icy")
   't s cy'
   ```
4. Using comprehension as a filter,

   ```
   >>> "".join([char for char in "it is icy" if char != "i"])
   't s cy'
   ```
5. Using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function

   ```
   >>> "".join(filter(lambda char: char != "i", "it is icy"))
   't s cy'
   ```

**Timing comparison**

```
def findreplace(m_string, char):
    m_string = list(m_string)
    for k in m_string:
        if k == char:
            del(m_string[m_string.index(k)])
    return "".join(m_string)

def replace(m_string, char):
    return m_string.replace("i", "")

def translate(m_string, char):
    return m_string.translate(None, "i")

from timeit import timeit

print timeit("findreplace('it is icy','i')", "from __main__ import findreplace")
print timeit("replace('it is icy','i')", "from __main__ import replace")
print timeit("translate('it is icy','i')", "from __main__ import translate")
```

**Result**

```
1.64474582672
0.29278588295
0.311302900314
```

`str.replace` and `str.translate` methods are 8 and 5 times faster than the accepted answer.

**Note:** Comprehension method and filter methods are expected to be slower, *for this case*, since they have to create list and then they have to be traversed again to construct a string. And `re` is a bit overkill for a single character replacement. So, they all are excluded from the timing comparison.

Comment: Would .translate(maketrans('','')) be the same as .translate(None)?

Comment: Arguably, regex could perform better for more complex examples, and would have been nice to see. But, great answer!

Comment: "are 8 and 5 times faster than the accepted answer", there is no accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

Try `str.replace()`:

```
my_string = "it is icy"
print my_string.replace("i", "")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `str` as a variable

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = 'it is icy'.replace('i', '', 1)
>>> x
't is icy'
```

Since your code would only replace the first instance, I assumed that's what you wanted. If you want to replace them all, leave off the `1` argument.

Since you cannot replace the character in the string itself, you have to reassign it back to the variable. (Essentially, you have to update the reference instead of modifying the string.)

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` method will work for this. Here is the code that will help to remove character from string. lets say

```
j_word = 'Stringtoremove'
word = 'String'    

for letter in word:
    if j_word.find(letter) == -1:
        continue
    else:
       # remove matched character
       j_word = j_word.replace(letter, '', 1)

#Output
j_word = "toremove"
```

Comment: thanks. I am looking same method to totally remove "Stringtoremove" when there is any substring "String". Do you have any idea towards it?

Comment: Whats the input in your case @Azam? Better if you put a separate question if input is tottaly different.

Comment: suppose I have list a=['8000 250V320 FEW015CB', '9000 120V180 SCT014']. I wish to remove the second parameter that having V at middle and retain others like a=['8000 FEW015CB', '9000 SCT014']. The parameter may be appear at any location, maybe at element no1 or 2 or 3. Any idea?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest split (not saying that the other answers are invalid, this is just another way to do it):

```
def findreplace(char, string):
   return ''.join(string.split(char))
```

Splitting by a character removes all the characters and turns it into a list. Then we join the list with the join function. You can see the ipython console test below

```
In[112]: findreplace('i', 'it is icy')
Out[112]: 't s cy'
```

And the speed...

```
In[114]: timeit("findreplace('it is icy','i')", "from __main__ import findreplace")
Out[114]: 0.9927914671134204
```

Not as fast as replace or translate, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
# s1 == source string
# char == find this character
# repl == replace with this character
def findreplace(s1, char, repl):
    s1 = s1.replace(char, repl)
    return s1

# find each 'i' in the string and replace with a 'u'
print findreplace('it is icy', 'i', 'u')
# output
''' ut us ucy '''
```