# Filtering objects from lists in python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to program something that will filter all the vowels out of a string of text and I'm not sure why my function doesn't work. Here's my code

```
def anti_vowel(text):
 letters = text.split() #make a list of all the letters in the string
 index = 0 #for del
 for x in letters:
     if x == "a" or x == "A" or x == "u" or x == "U" or x == "i" or x == "I" or x == "o" or x == "O" or x == "e" or x == "E":
         del letters[index]
     index += 1 #to make the if-clause work
 return "".join(letters) #turn the edited list into a string
```

While iterating over letters the if-clause should be activated when the object in letters is a vowel right? so it should delete that object. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not alterate a list while iterating through it.

Comment: [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: You are using `del letters[index]`. The list is getting smaller and smaller, and when you do `index += 1` you are actually skipping over an element(which was moved because of the delete).

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22187309/1903116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't iterating through letters, it's iterating through words. This is because `text.split()` splits your text into a `list` of whitespace-separated "word" strings.

The next problem is that you're iterating through a `list` and deleting entries. Mutating an iterable while iterating through it is a common cause of strange results.

Instead, do something like this:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.lower() not in 'aeioe', text))
```

Result:

```
>>> anti_vowel('hi my name is joe')
'h my nm s j'
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
re.sub(r'(?i)[AEIOU]', '', st)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier helps to do case insensitive match.
- `[AEIOU]` matches any one charcater from the given list. Since we already added the case-insensitive modifier, this would match both upper and lowercase vowels.

Comment: Mind adding a link to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub) there?

Answer (score 2):

I rather Avinash's approach, but if you want to fix your impl. here's how to do it:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    letters = list(text)
    i = 0
    while i < len(letters):
        x = letters[i]
        if x in "aAeEiIoOuU":
            del letters[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    return "".join(letters)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the `letters = text.split()` splits the text into words that were separated by whitespace, not letters. Also, modifying what you're iterating over is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Keeping `text.split()`, this will only work if the string contains whitespace between each character.

Comment: `if x in "aAeEiIoOuU":` would be more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

`''.join(c for c in text if c.lower() not in 'aeiou')`

This uses a generator expression to look at each letter in the string, and only keep it if it is not a vowel (its lowercase is not in 'aeiou'), then joins these valid characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and create something like this

```
def anti_vowel2(text):
    return "".join([x for x in text if x.lower() not in 'aeiou'])

print(anti_vowel2("test"))
```

which outputs the string `tst`

Comment: You can refactor that long predicate into simply `if x.lower() not in 'aeiou'`.