# How to remove hyphens from a list of strings

Tags: python

```
['0-0-0', '1-10-20', '3-10-15', '2-30-20', '1-0-5', '1-10-6', '3-10-30', '3-10-4']
```

How can I remove all the hyphens between the numbers?

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for example. Your question seems overly generic. Did you try solving it yourself first?

Comment: Look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187233/how-to-delete-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-python).

Comment: There are countless similar questions already on StackOverflow. Your first step shoudl be to read the documentation (you will find many string methods there). Your next step before posting a new question is seeing if such a question has been asked already.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to guide on how SO works and for your questions: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 15):

You can just iterate through with a for loop and replace each instance of a hyphen with a blank.

```
hyphenlist = ['0-0-0', '1-10-20', '3-10-15', '2-30-20', '1-0-5', '1-10-6', '3-10-30', '3-10-4']
newlist = []

for x in hyphenlist:
    newlist.append(x.replace('-', ''))
```

This code should give you a newlist without the hyphens.

Answer (score 10):

Or as a list comprehension:

```
>>>l=['0-0-0', '1-10-20', '3-10-15', '2-30-20', '1-0-5', '1-10-6', '3-10-30', '3-10-4']
>>>[i.replace('-','') for i in l] 
['000', '11020', '31015', '23020', '105', '1106', '31030', '3104']
```