# Python: How to remove all quotations from a text file?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file which has quotations in the form `'` and `"`. This text file is of the form.

```
"string1", "string2", 'string3', 'string4', ''string5'', etc.
```

How can I remove all of the quotations `'` and `"` while leaving the rest of the file the way it is now?

I suspect it should be something like this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write(line.strip())
```

Where `line.strip()` somehow strips the strings of the quotation marks. Is anything else required?

Comment: I'd use a generator expression to filter out the quotes instead: `''.join(c for c in line if c not in '"\'')`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187233/how-to-delete-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-python ShanZhengYang, if that answers your question, let us know.

Comment: You could use `replace()` but I wonder how these quotations marks got here. I hope you're not writing out python objects to text files, you should use `pickle` or similar instead

Comment: @Robᵩ The problem with `replace()` is that as implemented below, it also removes parentheses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close. Instead of `str.strip()`, try `str.replace()`:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write(line.replace('"', '').replace("'", ""))
```

Comment: With all due respect, @ShanZhengYang, I don't believe you. Nothing in the code I posted removes parentheses.

Comment: Looking through the text file, I unfortunately did make a mistake. Deleted above. The parentheses are still there. However, there are several quotations that still exist, especially nearby parentheses `("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4")`

Comment: Again, respectfully, I don't believe you. Can you provide a one-line `input.txt` file that, when handed to the 3-line program above, behaves that way?

Comment: For this behavior, it's probably best to see the entire text file.